# Unhandled promise rejection when making connection to MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

Hello there is my code below I have a problem since this afternoon I have two errors in the console:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection.
>   This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
>   (node:90699) [DEP0018]
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promiserejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejectionsthat are not handled will terminate the Node.js process witha non-zero exit code.

I switched to mongo client upstairs I think it's fine though the promised line 11 I think it's not fine

```
import {MongoClient} from 'mongodb'

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/chatapp', 
  {userNewUrlParser:true});


  export default class Database{

  connect(){

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        MongoClient.connect(URL, (err, db) => {

            return err ? reject(err) : resolve(db);
        });
    });
  }
}
```

What's wrong? What's missing?

Comment: Delete the third line, where connect is called early.  That's a hint, though, that the connect method won't work either

Comment: Update this line and try: useNewUrlParser instead of userNewUrlParser

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/chatapp', 
  {useNewUrlParser:true});

Comment: Use `MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/chatapp',   {userNewUrlParser:true}).then(console.log, console.error);` (or in general, append `.catch(console.error)` to your promise chains)!